# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'favorites.true' in 'where clause'の対処について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

以下のエラーが解消できず困っております。

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in NutritionsController#destroy
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'favorites.true' in 'where clause'
```

パラメータは以下になります。

```
{"_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"i0BwagvJ5opWqMTriPNDgX6HXIgqqnhUUpgUWOFPmeUVjOSkC5FOw63ZPU24kv5R0J6z4nnJqIzpsV/fUtSIQA==", "id"=>"29"}
```

userが登録済みのnutrition（食材）を削除するという簡単な動作です。
destroyアクションをビューから呼び出している際に発生していると思われます。
対象のコードは以下になります。

【ビュー】index.html.erb　★末尾から３行目でdestroyアクションを呼び出しております。

```
<% @nutritions.each do |nutrition| %>
        <tr height="60" class="content-post">
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <% if current_user.already_favorited?(nutrition, current_user) %>
              <td class="ingredient-column fav-color" id="ingredient-column">★<%= nutrition.ingredient %>
            <% else %>
              <td class="ingredient-column" id="ingredient-column"><%= nutrition.ingredient %>
            <% end %>
          <% else %>
            <td class="ingredient-column" id="ingredient-column"><%= nutrition.ingredient %>
          <% end %>
          <div class="more" id="more">
            <ul class="more-list" id="more-list">
              <li>

                <% if user_signed_in? %>
                  <% if current_user.already_favorited?(nutrition, current_user) %>
                    <%= link_to '解除', nutrition_favorites_path(user_id:current_user.id, nutrition_id:nutrition.id, id:0), method: :delete %>
                  <% else %>
                    <%= link_to '登録', user_favorites_path(user_id:current_user.id, nutrition_id:nutrition.id), method: :post %>
                  <% end %>
                  <% if current_user.id == nutrition.user.id %>
                    <%= link_to '編集', edit_nutrition_path(nutrition.id), method: :get %>
                    <%= link_to '削除', nutrition_path(nutrition.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: '削除しますか？'} %>
                  <% end %>
                <% end %>
```

【コントローラー】★ここのdestroyアクション時にエラーが発生しております。

```
class NutritionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :move_to_index, except: [:index]
  before_action :set_nutrition, only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @nutritions = Nutrition.includes(:user).order("nutritions.id DESC")
  end

  def new
    @nutrition = Nutrition.new
  end

  def create
    Nutrition.create(nutrition_params)
  end

  def search
    @nutritions = Nutrition.search(params[:keyword])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @nutrition.update(nutrition_params)
  end

  def destroy
    nutrition = Nutrition.find(params[:id])
    nutrition.destroy   ★エラー箇所★
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
  end


private

  def set_nutrition
    @nutrition = Nutrition.find(params[:id])
  end

  def nutrition_params
    params.require(:nutrition).permit(:ingredient, :calorie, :protein, :lipid, :carbohydrate, :potassium, :calcium, :iron, :vitamin_a, :vitamin_b1, :vitamin_b2, :vitamin_c, :salt_equivalent).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end

  def move_to_index
    unless user_signed_in?
      redirect_to action: :index
    end
  end

end
```

【ルーティング】routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root to: 'nutritions#index'
  resources :nutritions do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
    member do
      post "add", to: "favorites#create"
    end

    resource :favorites, only: [:destroy]
  end

  resources :users do
    resources :favorites, only: [:show, :create]
  end

end
```

【モデル】favoritesという中間テーブルとアソシエーションを組んでおります。
nutrition.rb

```
class Nutrition < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :favorites, foreign_key: true, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :fav_users, through: :favorites, source: :user

  with_options presence: true do
    validates :ingredient
    validates :calorie, numericality: { only_integer: true }
    validates :protein, numericality: { only_integer: true }
    validates :lipid, numericality: { only_integer: true }
    validates :carbohydrate, numericality: { only_integer: true }
    validates :potassium, numericality: { only_integer: true }
    validates :calcium, numericality: { only_integer: true }
    validates :iron, numericality: { only_integer: true }
    validates :vitamin_a, numericality: { only_integer: true }
    validates :vitamin_b1, numericality: { only_integer: true }
    validates :vitamin_b2, numericality: { only_integer: true }
    validates :vitamin_c, numericality: { only_integer: true }
    validates :salt_equivalent, numericality: { only_integer: true }
  end

  def self.search(search)
    if search != ""
      Nutrition.where('ingredient LIKE(?)', "%#{search}%")
    else
      Nutrition.all
    end
  end
end
```

favorite.rb

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :nutrition
  validates_uniqueness_of :nutrition_id, scope: :user_id
end
```

エラーメッセージでは `Unknown column 'favorites.true' in 'where clause'` とありますが、今回のdestroyアクションではfavoritesに全く触れているつもりはないのですがなぜここで出てきてしまうのでしょうか。

アソシエーションにてdependent: :destroyが組んであるので試しに消去してみると以下のエラーが発生します。

```
Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`berries_development`.`favorites`, CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_2201ed1284` FOREIGN KEY (`nutrition_id`) REFERENCES `nutritions` (`id`))
```

何が原因なのかがわかりません・・・
ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: 外部キー制約が入っているようですが、それは意図したものですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
初心者なのもので参考しているサイトに習って導入したという経緯です。
外部キーについて改めて調べました。
「外部キー制約があるとき、子テーブルに外部キーがあるとき、親テーブルのレコードは消せない」というルールを見つけたので、試しに子テーブル（favorites）のレコードをすべて消した上で親テーブル（nutritions）のレコードの削除(destroyアクション)を試みたのですが、同じエラーが発生してしまいました。

外部キー制約と同時にdependent: :destroyも記載しているので問題は無いと思いこんでいるのですが・・・

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Nutrition`モデルの`has_many`アソシエーションに`foreign_key: true`とありますが、`foreign_key`は外部キーとなる**カラムを指定する**オプションです。（true/falseのbooleanを渡すものではない）
そのためMySqlが「favoritesテーブルにtrueという名前のカラムはないよ」とエラーを吐いています。

外部キーとなるカラムを指定するようにしてください。
なお、railsの命名規約に従っている（nutrition_idとしている）場合はforeign_keyオプションは必要ありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
foreign_keyを削除したところ、正常に動作しました！

Comment: 良かったです。解決したらちゃんと回答を承認しておいてくださいね。